# Disabling thumbnails in Nautilus using dconf

Tags: debian, gnome, nautilus, dconf, gsettings

Bellow are the steps I undertook to try to disable thumbnails in
Nautilus ( following instruction mentioned here:
https://wiki.gnome.org/dconf/SystemAdministrators ) . It didn't help.
(I'm on Debian Wheezy, which seemingly has no /etc/dconf by default):

- `mkdir -p /etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks`
- `nano /etc/dconf/db/local.d/settings`

  ```
  # /etc/dconf/db/local.d/settings
  # prevent showing thumbnails
  [org.gnome.nautilus.preferences]
  show-image-thumbnails="never"
  ```
- `nano /etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/settings`

  ```
  # prevent changes to showing thumbnails setting
  org.gnome.nautilus.preferences.show-image-thumbnails
  ```
- `mkdir /etc/dconf/profile`
- `nano /etc/dconf/profile/local`

  ```
  system-db:local
  ```
- `export DCONF_PROFILE=/etc/dconf/profile`
- `dconf update`

What's wrong here?

I also tried to disable it using `dconf-editor` (both as root and as
regular user) and I was not able to change the setting from 'local-only'
to 'never' it looked like it was locked.

I also tried `gsettings`:

```
# gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.preferences show-image-thumbnails 'local-only'

# gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences show-image-thumbnails "never"

** (process:5834): WARNING **: The connection is closed

** (process:5834): WARNING **: The connection is closed
```

PS:
I didn't reboot. Do I need to reboot in order for the new settings to
take effect?

I found several dconf files but it doesn't look like they contain any
lock of org.gnome.nautilus.preferences.show-image-thumbnails  and
adding

```
[org.gnome.nautilus.preferences]
show-image-thumbnails="never"
```

to them didn't help either. Here are they:

```
/var/lib/gdm3/.cache/dconf
/var/lib/gdm3/.cache/dconf/user
/var/lib/gdm3/dconf/db
/var/lib/gdm3/dconf/profile
/var/lib/gdm3/dconf/db/gdm
/var/lib/gdm3/dconf/db/gdm.d
/var/lib/gdm3/dconf/db/gdm.d/00-upstream-settings
/var/lib/gdm3/dconf/db/gdm.d/10-desktop-base-settings
/var/lib/gdm3/dconf/db/gdm.d/90-debian-settings
/var/lib/gdm3/dconf/db/gdm.d/locks
/var/lib/gdm3/dconf/db/gdm.d/locks/00-upstream-settings-locks
/var/lib/gdm3/dconf/profile/gdm
```

and

```
/usr/share/gdm/dconf
/usr/share/gdm/dconf-profile
/usr/share/gdm/dconf/00-upstream-settings
/usr/share/gdm/dconf/10-desktop-base-settings
/usr/share/gdm/dconf/locks
/usr/share/gdm/dconf/locks/00-upstream-settings-locks
```

It looks like dconf update ignores:

```
/etc/dconf/db/local.d/settings
```

because if I intentionally  write wrong things there it doesn't
complain.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's needed but you should at least restart Gnome if not the computer just to make sure that makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the same subtle issue I stumbled over for a while...
Look at the dconf(7) man page carefully.

You're trying to set `DCONF_PROFILE` to a directory, not to a file.
Really, this isn't necessary, since effectively `DCONF_PROFILE` defaults
to `user`, so just name the file `/etc/dconf/profile/user` to ensure it
gets read:

```
 # cat /etc/dconf/profile/user 
 user-db:user
 system-db:local
 #
```

As long as `dconf update` does generate a `/etc/dconf/db/local` file
(from whatever is in `/etc/dconf/db/local.d/`), then this should all
take effect.